# Android Emulator is not working after update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently I updated my Android SDK and emulator. After that I'm not able to run the 'Hello world' program. While loading the emulator I am getting warnings and error like this.

```
OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only.
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
TextureDraw: Could not create/link program: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio output failed
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
audio: Failed to create voice `dac'
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
draw: no program
draw: no program
.
.
.
ANGLE: egl::`anonymous-namespace'::CreateDisplayFromAttribs: make D3D display
ANGLE: D3D9: rx::Renderer9::generateConfigs
```

I tried lots of uninstall and update, downgrade of sdk, etc., but nothing is working and I'm not able to get the exact problem.

I have installed 2 SDK platforms:

1. Android 7.0
2. Android 4.2

My SDK tools are:
[image]

Comment: hi man, you get the solution to this problem or not?

Comment: if you got the answer please share

Comment: currently, i am using Bluestacks.In my point of view it is better to compare with an emulator.

Comment: thanks man for your reply

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the solution is to change "the amount of physical RAM" when you create a virtual device android... make 512 MB because your computer can't read a space (1.5 GB ) in RAM.

How to create a virtual device correctly to solve this problem?

First, open Android Studio, then click <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Android</kbd> > <kbd>AVD Manager</kbd>.

Second, click <kbd>Create virtual Device</kbd> after choose a device (for example : nexus 4) and click <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Select a system Image</kbd>, then click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

Third, click <kbd>Show Advanced Settings</kbd>; scroll until you see "RAM" and change the value to a lower value, for example 512MB.